# Возможность коммита с заранее обнуленными (пустыми) переменными

Tags: git, github

Имеется проект с исходниками (на python), которые я регулярно выкладываю на Github. В нём присутствуют переменные (пока что одна, является токеном: `TOKEN="..."`), которые я не хочу выкладывать для всеобщего доступа. Однако у себя в процессе отладки и проверки эти переменные заполняю соответствующими значениями.

До этого я просто вручную перед коммитом удалял значение, потом, в процессе запуска и прочего, вставлял значение снова. Но теперь меня интересует, есть ли в Git возможность обнулять определенную переменную перед коммитом и пушем?

Пока что я вижу 2 выхода без использования возможностей Git:

- либо иметь экспортируемый конфигурационный файл, который можно не использовать в общем репозитории; но пока что ради 1 переменной я считаю это избыточным решением;
- либо просто написать однострочник с `sed``ом, что не так интересно, в отличие от познавания возможностей Git. Да и костыльно это, по-моему.

Comment: Обычно такие вещи просто выносят в переменные окружения или конфиг.

Comment: @Nofate, вы б ответ соорудили бы подробный - мне тоже интересно как это правильно запилить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а про что тут развернуто рассказывать? Можете меня в чате спросить, если какие-то детали интересуют.

Comment: @Nofate, ну, я думаю было бы многим полезно увидеть в ответе пример... Например есть строка в коде или в ресурсах и как её и куда перенести, чтобы её и использовать легко было и в открытый доступ не попадало... Вроде я как-то на хабре видел статейку на сей счёт... Там как-то чрез `BUILD.CONFIG` это предлагали решать и в `gradle` чего-то там ещё прописывалось, вроде... А константа в коде брала как раз из билда значение-строку...

Comment: @Nofate как это правильней сделать в моей ситуации? Вы бы вынесли даже и одну переменную в отдельный конфиг?

Comment: Конфигурацию вынести в отдельный коммит **возможно**, но **поддерживать задолбаетесь** %)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В папке проекта создайте подпапку для скрытых конфигов. Добавьте её в `.gitignore`. Если приложению не требуется читать её от другого пользователя, ограничьте права.

```
mkdir .hidden
chmod 0600 .hidden
echo '.hidden' >> .gitignore
```

Почему папку, а не просто файл: потому что однажды вы можете его случайно переименовать, закоммитить и запушить. И ваш токен будет навсегда потерян, потому что гитхаб зеркалируется в реальном времени. Вариант с хуком я считаю опасным по той же причине — вы можете переименовать переменную в конфиге или как-то изменить формат, после чего хук тихо и молча не сработает.

В этой папке и храните конфиги с токенами в любом удобном вам формате. Конфиг даже для одной переменной — это нормально. Ваш ssh-ключ это, грубо говоря, тоже одна большая строка в файле.

Answer (score 3):

вы, конечно, можете написать **локальный** [перехватчик pre-commit](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git) такого примерно вида:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/sh
sed -i 's/parol=.*/parol=/' file
```

здесь просто в файле `file` (лежащем в корне рабочей копиии) в строке, содержащей `parol=`, будет удалено всё после `parol=`, **перед** внесением *commit-а*. не забудьте присвоить бит исполнимости файлу с перехватчиком: `$ chmod u+x .git/hooks/pre-commit`.

главный недостаток: это будет работать только в вашей локальной копии репозитория.

---

но, вероятно, более *правильным* будет вынесение настроек в отдельный конфигурационный файл, который не будет включен в репозиторий (для «красоты» неплохо его упомянуть в файле `.gitignore`).

Comment: в итоге первая часть совета - это и есть то самое самописное решение, которое вовсе не изящно. Но про pre-commit я не знал, спасибо.

Не зная Git, я подумал, что есть готовое решение, которое я просто не нашел в мануале.

Comment: @approximatenumber, нет, «готового решения», насколько мне известно, в природе не существует.

Comment: хотя какая разница, лежит ли скрипт просто отдельно или в своем локальном репозитории...